# flutter internet connection issue after publishing by app-bundle

Tags: java, flutter, dart, google-play, apk

When I produce my apk from the command:
`flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64`
I don't have any internet issue.

my manifest use these permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

but I have published my appbundle to google-play from command: `flutter build appbundle` but strangely today I noticed that users have internet issue.

I followed instructions on [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#test-the-app-bundle) for testing appbundle and the generated apk was fine.
for that I don't have any clue what's the problem is, any help is appreciated.

thanks

is it possible that this issue comes from sign certificate issue for google-play ?

Comment: It's probably not a certificate issue. Does the app crash on the users' devices?

Comment: no, that's fine, users will be stuck into registration page, the release-apk works very well but google-play users can't proceed

Comment: Are you using any firebase related plugins for registration / login like Google Sign in or firebase auth mechanisms?

Comment: yes, I'm using google sign in